# C# MSMQ XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, msmq

I have a problem with serializing the list of objects to message for MSMQ. The thing what I am trying to do is:

We have a Booking object, and two integers that we want to send through the message.

```
List<object> parameters = new List<object>();
parameters.Add(booking);
parameters.Add(int1);
parameters.Add(int2);
...
message.Body = parameters;
mq.Send(message);
```

When I am trying to send a message, I am getting the exception:

> The type MasterModel.Model.Booking.Booking was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

I have no Base class for Booking class. I am kind of stuck at this point, I have read a big part of solutions, but never found a proper one for my case.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Have you used `XmlInclude` or `SoapInclude`?

Comment: `List<object>` is going to be awkward because `object` is awkward; it won't be able to correctly deserialize xml without knowing what the types are in advance. It can kinda get around this for the root object (ish), but... I wonder if you could use something like `public class MyData { public Booking Booking {get;set;} public int Foo {get;set;} public int Bar {get;set;} }` and populate *that*: `message.Body = new MyData { Booking = booking, Foo = int1, Bar = int2};`

Comment: Yes I did it as You said Marc and it works, thanks for help.